# Flask API run on Docker but can't access

Tags: api, docker, flask

I'm trying to run my API with Docker. I've managed to build and run it but, when I test it in Postman, it doesn't work.
I have a folder that contains uhopper.py(which is the API), requirements.txt and Dockerfile.
Everything seems to work but when I make a GET request on "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile/john" it doesn't give a response and an error occurs ("There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile/john.")
I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

uhopper.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

john = {
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Writers_from_Belfast": 1,
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:People_educated_at_Newstead_Wood_School": 2,
}

mac = {
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1998_establishments_in_New_York": 1,
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Public_Interest_Research_Groups": 1,
}

class Profile(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        if name == 'john':
            return john, 200
        elif name == 'mac':
            return mac, 200
        return "Not found", 400

api.add_resource(Profile, "/profile/<string:name>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask>=1.1.1
Flask-RESTful>=0.3.7
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /uhopper
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["uhopper.py"]
```

This is my Git Bash:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the Flask import:

```
from flask import Flask
```

You can reorder the Dockerfile to save duplicating the path:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /uhopper
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["uhopper.py"]
```

I think it's good practice to use the absolute path `CMD ["/uhopper/uhopper.py"]`

I encourage you to specify (at least minimum) versions of imports too:

```
Flask>=1.1.1
Flask-RESTful>=0.3.7
```

Comment: I've done everything you've said but still isn't working. (I had already imported Flask but when I wrote the question I forgot to write that line, now it's updated and I wrote everything you've recommended)

Comment: If you're using Docker on Windows, I think you can't use `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) to reach the container. You can prove this by running a known-working solution (e.g. Nginx) perhaps `docker run --interactive --tty --publish=80:80 nginx` and then trying to `curl http://localhost:80`. I suspect that doesn't work for you either?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. (exactly I'm on Windows) What should I do to reach the container?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with running Docker on Windows. Does `docker-machine ip` yield an IP? If it does, try that IP's port 5000.

Comment: Someone else answered but it's gone. You are running `docker run --publish=5000:5000 ...` right? Perhaps add `--interactive --tty` to view the logs more easily too.

Comment: I've tried again with the docker-machine ip and now it works! Don't know what happened before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good! Was the issue the correct IP? Publishing the port? Or a little of both?

Comment: The IP was the issue, now with the IP of the virtual machine it works!

Comment: Super. Thanks for letting me know